# Clojure - Inclusive Range

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I am using Clojure to do the following task -

```
Write a function named get-divisors which takes a number n as input and returns the all the numbers between 2 and √ inclusive
```

I have this code so far, that seems to be working as expected:

```
  (defn get-divisors [n]
   (str (range 2 (Math/sqrt n))))
```

The user inserts and input and the code shall display all numbers between 2 and the square root of that particular number. (I know! get-divisors is a horrible name for the function)

I type `(get-divisors 101)` I get the following output
`"(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)"` which is correct.

However, the issue is when I use the number `4` I get a result of nil or `()` when I should in-fact get `2`. Or when I enter `49` I should get all numbers between `2` and `7` but I only get all the numbers between `2` and `6`.

I have searched online for some information. I am new to Clojure however, the information on this programming seems to be scarce as opposed to the likes of `Java`, `JavaScript`. I have read another thread which was based on a similar situation to mind, however, the suggestions/answers didn't work for me unfortunately.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [the Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html).  `range` [does not include the upper bound](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range).  So, in general, you probably want something like

```
(range 2 (inc n))
```

or in your case

```
(range 2 (inc (Math/floor (Math/sqrt n))))
```

Also check out http://clojure.org

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I have accepted your answer. Once again, thank you. I wish you a good day!